# Asymptotic expansion of a special peicewise function

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, piecewise-continuity

My professor challenged me to determine an asymptotic expansion of this piecewise function :

$$f(x) =
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
xsin(1/x) & if & x \in \mathbb{Q} & \\ 
 \\ x & if & x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

What I did immediately was to calculate the limit of x.sin(1/x) as x approaches 0 which is equal to 0, then I wrote f(x) = o(1) if x $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ since its limit is zero.

However, I couldn't continue solving the problem and I really can't figure out the next step.

Comment: The function is only continuous at $0$ and $\frac 2{(2k+1)\pi}$. It isn't asymptotic to anything nice.